# 3d co-ordinates from UV map

Tags: uv

i want to use a Uv and occlusion map to generate a new mesh over the top of an existing mesh but with different topology.

My logic goes like this:

Create an occlusion and UV map from an existing model.

Generate a new UV map over the top of the old one with a different shape.

Use the old UV coordinates to project new UV map into 3d vertices.

In other words, i want to use the old useless topology to provide the x,y,z info for a new topology via a UV map.

Is it possible to get the x, y, z info from the UV map?

**heres a before:**

[image]

**Heres an after:**
[image]

Comment: I'm not at all an expert at this, but that sounds like a convoluted and imprecise method for something that sounds like a simple retopology. Why not use a *Shrinkwrap* modifier instead, and make the new mesh conform to the old one?

Comment: so i can make a new 2d UV mesh and shrink wrap it to the old mesh?

Comment: the reason i need the mesh in 2d is because i am generating the mesh FROM the occlusion map

Comment: Is it an occlusion map or a height map? Anyway, yes, you can make one mesh conform to another through a [Shrinkwrap Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html)

Comment: im using the occlusion map as a feature to a machine learning algorithm that will generate topology based on the attributes of the occlusion map